# Cufon don't exclude the elements with the selector :not

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, fonts, font-face, cufon

I searched on the web and stackoverflow a solution for **exclude an element** of Cufon transformation, because my font '**BlueHighwayDType**' dosen't contains the '**€**' symbol so I must exclude this element for be able see it on the ie7/8.
http://www.matteowebdesigner.com/test/yesimove/

```
<!--head-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Blue_Highway_D_Type_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mind-ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

The elements that I want replace are **p** and the element that I want exclude is **span.small**

```
<!--body-->
<article>
    <p>L'unico <strong>Personal Trainer</strong> <br/>
    che ti segue ovunque</p>
    <p>e ti permette di <strong>condividere</strong> 
    i tuoi progressi con i tuoi amici.</p>
    <p>A soli <strong>9.<span class="small">99 &euro;</span></strong> al mese !</p>
</article>
```

So I tried the example that i find on the web and I used the selector '**:not**' but it dosen't worked. look this:

```
/*mind-ie.js*/
$(document).ready(function() { // Start Functions
    Cufon.replace('#main #slogan section article p:not(.small)');
});
```

I don't understand because it doesn't work, I thought the selector was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if in this case exclude all span element.

```
Cufon.replace('#main #slogan section article p',{ignore:{span:true}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `small` class is actually exposed by the descendant `<span>` element, not by the `<p>` element.

Try using the [:has()](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
Cufon.replace("#slogan section article p:not(:has(.small))");
```

On second thought, this will ignore the `<p>` elements that contain elements matching `.small`, which may not be what you want. Specifying the `ignoreClass` option looks like a better idea:

```
Cufon.replace("#slogan section article p", {
    ignoreClass: "small"
});
```

Comment: I tried also in this way, but It exclude all third paragraph. Then I tryed also in this way `Cufon.exclude('#main #slogan section article p .small');` but the result dosen't change.

Comment: I think the error was that select the last all 'p', while the element that I must exclude is only the tag 'span'.

Comment: I think that's because Cufon transforms the whole content of matched elements, including descendants, but cannot exclude these descendants. Both `ignoreClass` and `exclude()` not working seem to point to that...

Comment: I used this method:
`Cufon.replace(['#header ul.primary:eq(0) > li > a','#main #slogan section article p'],{ignore:{span:true}});`
Now it's working. It isn't very nice but at least it work.

Comment: @Matteo, it will ignore all `<span>` elements, but there might be no adverse effects to that in your particular case. I would suggest you post your solution in your own answer, then accept it when the 48-hour delay ends in order to resolve your question. Cheers :)

Comment: I think as you, I would wanted use the css selector or however something that selected of more v_v. However you are right now insert my "solution", even if It isn't much elegant.